# If/elseif statement within wp_mail function

Tags: wp-mail

I need to know what is wrong with my if statement here:

```
//EMAIL ADMIN BASED ON PROBLEM_TYPE
function new_post_creation_email() {
    global $post;
    $postid = $post->ID;
    $problem_type = get_post_meta($postid, 'problem_type', true);
    $description = the_content();
    if ($problem_type = 'phones') {
        $to = '1st email here';
    }
    elseif ($problem_type = 'computers') {
        $to = '2nd email here';
    }
    else {
        $to = '3rd email here';
    }
    $subject = "New Ticket in " . get_post_meta($postid, 'problem_type', true);
    $message = "A new ticket has been added.  Please login to view and print.";

    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message);
}
```

**Emails are correct in actual code**
Currently, the message sends but the same email arrives multiple times in my 1st email address, not the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

This is problem with your PHP syntax, not WP. You are using assignment (`=`) where you should be using comparison (`==`).

So this:

```
if( $problem_type = 'phones' )
```

should really be this:

```
if( 'phones' == $problem_type )
```

And same for other condition.